# detect touch of subview of uiview being animated using CAAnimation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, caanimation

I'm trying to detect a touch on a UISubview of a view being animated

Here's my detection code:

```
//simple but not very elegant way of getting correct frame
CGRect keepFrame = self.fishContainer.layer.frame;
self.fishContainer.layer.frame = [[self.fishContainer.layer presentationLayer] frame];

//get touch location, taking presentation layer into account. (See above)
CGPoint p = [sender locationInView:self.fishContainer];
CALayer *layer =[self.fishContainer.layer presentationLayer];

//apply relevant transform
p = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(p,layer.affineTransform);
    EBLog(@"checking point %@",NSStringFromCGPoint(p));
UIView *vToRemove = nil;

//find topmost view containing touched point
for (UIView *v in self.parasites) {
    EBLog(@"-BOUND %@",NSStringFromCGRect(v.frame));

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(v.frame, p))
    {
        vToRemove = v;
    }
}
//OK, we have a view. Let's remove it.
if(vToRemove)
{
    EBLog(@"found one");
    [vToRemove removeFromSuperview];
    [self.parasites removeObject:vToRemove];
    if ([self.parasites count] == 0) {
        [self showWinnerScreen];
        [self stopGame];
    }
}

//restore view frame
self.fishContainer.layer.frame = keepFrame;
```

Everything works correctly as long as I don't animate `parasiteArea` parentview.

When I animate `parasiteArea`'s parentview (A `CAAnimation` consisting of move of the view, scale of the view, and rotate of the view) , the touch is outside the bounds of the expected subview.

**UPDATE**

I manged to get the detection working in most cases (see code above), by using the `presentationLayer` property and  `CGPointApplyAffineTransform`. There is however, still some cases where it dosnt work.

I guess I need to translate the touch point to the coordinate space of the `CAAnimation`.

Or something like that? any suggestions?

Comment: You may get a proper momentary representation of an animated layer by checking the frame of its `presentationLayer` - check the CALayer reference on that property.

Comment: Hi Till. Thanks for your comment. That is actually what I'm working on right now in combination with CGPointApplyAffineTransform. It is however, not working in all cases. Still trying to figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `UIView animateWithDuration` instead of `CAAninmation`. For my purpose the limited animation possibles were enough.